Graph API working with Web API but throwing error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present in Blazor app using same code
I managed to get Microsoft Graph API set up and working in a Web API app where a post request is successful to obtain the bearer token and again to send the email.
However, when I use the same code in Blazor, I get a CORS error when attempting the post request to authenticate and the error is the standard one you get when there is no Cors (I replaced the tenant with TENANT below):

Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'https://localhost:7253' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I can't understand what could be different about a Blazor project that would stop this working when it works fine in Web API and both are accessing the same Microsoft URL and only one gets blocked due to CORS on the requested resource aside from the fact that Web API runs from the server and Blazor runs from the browser unless that it is.
This is the part of the code that calls the API:
string? loginEndPoint;
loginEndPoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

HttpResponseMessage formResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(loginEndPoint, formParamsEncoded);

I've essentially copied the same config file and same shared class that sends the email from the working Web API so the class that sends the email is identical.
If it isn't possible to make this work from Blazor then it means I will need to build my own Web API that I can add CORS to and call that first to then call the Microsoft API from my API which would be an added layer of complexity that shouldn't really be needed.
I did wonder if I could add NoCors headers from the calling Blazor end using SendAsync instead but that gave a server 400 error rather than the Cors error so not sure if that perhaps got further or not but it would seem SendAsync isn't sending the right sort of request and I'm not sure why:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, loginEndPoint);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
request.SetBrowserRequestCache(BrowserRequestCache.NoStore); //optional 
request.Content = formParamsEncoded;
HttpResponseMessage formResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

I've already spent hours trying to find a way to get this to work and send the email as it does with Web API projects so would appreciate any help.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71746006/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-set

Thanks I didn't realise I could add nocors from the request side if the server does not implement CORS. It seems surprising they do not implement it on the Graph API services and give you a place to specify your endpoints and make it more secure.

You failed due to browser security feature,see this doc
You could  follow this document :Sign in users in a single-page app (SPA) and call the Microsoft Graph API using Blazor WebAssembly

Thanks for the help on this. In the end I created a Web API project to make the process and code needed on the front end a bit simpler so I can just supply my API with the email address, a subject and an email using a simpler model and then have the huge set of Graph API models on the API and to help standardise the approach across the different projects I am working on. I realise CORS is only an issue if calling an API from the browser as presumably if you call it in C# code then the compiler knows you meant to call it from the server side.
